# How to tell sequelize what are the original column names to use when forming Joins (associations)?

Tags: sequelize.js

when defining associations, I don't know how to tell sequelize, what the names of my foreign keys (and primary keys in 'parent' tables, if needed), are.

I'am using a mssql (2008 r2) database that exists from years ago and I can't change anything in that db.

This are my models:

```
CuentasBancarias_sql = sequelize.define('cuentasBancarias_sql', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, field: 'CuentaInterna', allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
}, {
     tableName: 'CuentasBancarias'
});

Chequeras_sql = sequelize.define('chequeras_sql', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, field: 'NumeroChequera', allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    numeroCuenta: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, field: 'NumeroCuenta', allowNull: false },
}, {
     tableName: 'Chequeras'
});


MovimientosBancarios_sql = sequelize.define('movimientosBancarios_sql', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, field: 'ClaveUnica', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false },
    claveUnicaChequera: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, field: 'ClaveUnicaChequera', allowNull: false },
}, {
     tableName: 'MovimientosBancarios'
});
```

They are just 3 one-to-many tables, with primary keys and foreign keys. This is a very normal, simple and common model.

Now, these are my associations:

```
CuentasBancarias_sql.hasMany(Chequeras_sql, { foreignKey: 'NumeroCuenta'} );
Chequeras_sql.belongsTo(CuentasBancarias_sql, { foreignKey: 'NumeroCuenta' } );
Chequeras_sql.hasMany(MovimientosBancarios_sql, { foreignKey: 'ClaveUnicaChequera' } );
MovimientosBancarios_sql.belongsTo(Chequeras_sql, { foreignKey: 'ClaveUnicaChequera' } );
```

Everything seems to work fine. However, when I added the associations, *findAll* fails because it generates wrong column names in the *Join* in the sql select statement.

So, I think my question is: If I have an sql server database and I can't change anything, how can I tell sequelize the original (database) column names (pk and fk), so sequelize can construct correct Joins, when doing queries (findAll)?

This is how I write my query:

```
MovimientosBancarios_sql.findAndCountAll({
                where: { ... },
                include: [
                    { model: Chequeras_sql, include: [ { model: CuentasBancarias_sql }] },
                ],
            })
```

Many thanks for your help and bye ...

Comment: How are the column names wrong? I.e. what is the actual sql generated, and what is the sql you want?

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for your promptly reply. I did something that corrected the issue. However, I just don't know what specifically. I add more info below to elaborate. Thanks again ...

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment above, everything is working right now. Issue fixed. 
This is how I set my relations:

```
CuentasBancarias_sql.hasMany(Chequeras_sql, { foreignKey: 'NumeroCuenta'} );
Chequeras_sql.belongsTo(CuentasBancarias_sql, { foreignKey: 'NumeroCuenta' } );
Chequeras_sql.hasMany(MovimientosBancarios_sql, { foreignKey: 'ClaveUnicaChequera' } );
MovimientosBancarios_sql.belongsTo(Chequeras_sql, { foreignKey: 'ClaveUnicaChequera' } );
```

Sequelize correctly took the column names from *foreingKey* clauses to form the Joins in Select statement. This is how the Join part ended:

```
FROM [MovimientosBancarios] AS [movimientosBancarios_sql] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Chequeras] AS [chequeras_sql] 
ON [movimientosBancarios_sql].[ClaveUnicaChequera] = [chequeras_sql].[NumeroChequera] 
INNER JOIN [CuentasBancarias] AS [chequeras_sql.cuentasBancarias_sql] 
ON [chequeras_sql].[NumeroCuenta] = [chequeras_sql.cuentasBancarias_sql].[CuentaInterna] AND [chequeras_sql.cuentasBancarias_sql].[Cia] = 37
```

Note the *Inner Join* and the *Cia = 30* part, because the *where* part in my query below:

```
MovimientosBancarios_sql.findAndCountAll({
                where: filter,
                include: [
                    { model: Chequeras_sql, include: [ { model: CuentasBancarias_sql, where: { Cia: compania.numero } }] },
                ],
            })
```

Thanks again and bye ...